# ssh using password and key

Tags: ssh, openssh

Ubuntu 22.04 with OpenSSH

I was ssh to require key and password.  I want keys for the usual reason.  I also want password in case my laptop is lost or stolen.  I don't mind the extra step to type the password.  Is this unsmart for some reason?

Comment: Usually you log in using either key or password (not both after each other). Keys have much higher security. I don't understand why it would be an advantage with password, if the computer is stolen. In that case you should have encrypted disk (LVM with LUKS encryption) than you set during the installation.

Comment: Is it possible to have both?